# Apache html response returns gibberish

Tags: java, html, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to get an HTML response from a remote website, and I get something like this :

```
×¡×?×? ×?×? ×?×? ×?×?
```

instead of Hebrew letters or symbols.

Here is my code:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                    .build();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String s=null;
            if (entity != null) {
                 s= EntityUtils.toString(entity);          
            }
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What happens when you browse with a web browser to the remote website? Still looks like gibberish? If it doesn't, I would suggest it's a character encoding issue.

Comment: No - the website is fine.
How can I fix the encoding problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java I'm afraid, so I'm leaving that to people smarter than me in that regard :)

You could check if there's any properties or methods on either CloseableHttpClient or HttpGet related to character encoding though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs,

> The content is converted using the character set from the entity (if any), failing that, "ISO-8859-1" is used.

The default charset is being used because you don't provide one, which doesn't map those characters correctly - you should probably use UTF-8 instead. Try this.

```
s= EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```